# PHP Array Issue

Tags: php, arrays

I have two array **Array1** and **Array2**  and want to get related data from these arrays.
let me elaborate further.

**Array1**

```
Array
(
    [42] => 1
)
```

**Array2**

```
Array
(
    [42] => 30215
    [43] => 15478
)
```

Now i want to something like this.

```
 Array
    (
        [42] => 30215
    )
```

Comment: Would like to see your so far efforts to achieve this.

Comment: directly use array2.. no need of array1 ?

Comment: directly i want to opposite to array_diff_key()

Comment: Since in your first array your keys are not the values you don't have to flip it and just take the: `array_intersect_key()` of both arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `array_intersect_keys` will returns an associative array containing all the entries of array1 which have keys that are present in all arguments.
and `max` will find the highest value of those

```
$arr1 = Array
(
    '42' => 1
);
$arr2 = Array
(
    '42' => 30215,
    '43' => 15478
);
echo max(array_intersect_key($arr2, $arr1));//30215
```

Comment: thanks dear, i was just far to add _key :D